# YouTube iFrame API behavior is inconsistent/nondeterministic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube-api

I was having trouble isolating a bug in my JavaScript code for controlling Youtube videos via the iframe/HTML5 API.

I went back to the demo code on the main documentation page:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

...and to my surprise, I see the same inconsistent behavior even when I use the demo code from there and don't change anything.

The behavior is that some of the time, when I load this page, the player autoplays (which is the intent of the code), and other times it doesn't. It always does succeed in loading. Also, the player never seems to stop after 6 seconds, in contrary to what the comments say.

Breakpoints verify that part of the issue at least is that `onPlayerReady()` is not always being called. When I set a breakpoint in `onPlayerReady()`, it usually is not reached, and is only reached the times that the player goes on to succeed in autoplaying.

Of course, this behavior may be dependent on the speed and reliability of my internet connection, which is wired and otherwise seems decently fast. I just tested it -- 24 Mbps, and it seems pretty consistent.

If I make superficial changes to the html, that seems to sometimes prompt the page on loading to autoplay, but not always. Sometimes I will reload every few seconds 5 times in a row with no autoplay or onPlayerReady breakpoint being hit, then do it a 6th time and that time it will autoplay fine.

I'm using Chrome v30.0.1599.101 on Mac OS 10.8.4.

I know that code is in beta and in flux, and isn't supposed to be production level yet, but I was hoping there was something i can try.

Here is the code I'm using, **FYI**, in case the code posted on the api reference page above changes. Again, I'm not altering a single character.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was opening the page locally, which makes for different behavior in all sorts of little ways from how it works when delivered from a server. The browser client itself handles things like cacheing differently when content is local. When I put the same page on a server, it started to work every time.

In addition, FYI, for my bigger issue that led me down this rabbithole, I found that I needed to follow this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14952334/2308190 ...in order to get my YouTube callback functions to be called with jQuery loaded.

Comment: Getting inconsistent behavior on this now, served via dropbox: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1035381/abbreviator/youtubetest.html . Usually it plays from beginning for 6s (that's not correct behavior), sometimes it skips ahead and plays for more than 6s without stopping (also not correct behavior). This is on Win 7, Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m ("up to date" as of this date)

Comment: And on my actual project, which is more complex than the demo code YouTube provides, I'm getting inconsistency in whether or not the API js code ever calls the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady button. Sometimes right on loading page, sometimes never, with no code changes. This is on Win 7, Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m ("up to date" as of this date)

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation where my first YouTube iframe would load correctly, and subsequent ones would not.

The issue was caused by creating a new `YT.Player` before its `<div>` had been added to the DOM. This issue didn't occur the first time I created a `YT.Player`, because the YouTube API had to be loaded first. This caused a microsecond delay which allowed the rest of my code to execute, so the `<div>` was added to the DOM before the YouTube API finished loading.