# onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() not firing

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I've looked through so many questions and the youtube api stuff but for the life of me can't figure out why the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is not working.

Here is my iframe:

```
<iframe id="youtube_vid" width="763" height="430" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dlJshzOv2cw?theme=light&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

And my script:

```
function callYTapi() {

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    console.log('script loaded');

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        console.log('IframeAPI = Ready');
        var player = new YT.Player('youtube_vid', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
            console.log("Paused");
        }

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            console.log("Playing");
        }

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            end(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I get the console.log for the loaded script but not for Iframe ready or anything else. Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube iframe api not triggering onYouTubeIframeAPIReady](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256382/youtube-iframe-api-not-triggering-onyoutubeiframeapiready)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The callback functions must be in the global scope. Just move `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` and the others outside `callYTapi`.

Comment: Yes I just realized that!  Thanks Vincius!  I needed it in that function so I changed to window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() = function (){} and all is well...in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: I had a similar problem. For some reason the cover images wasn't loading up. I wrapped the API in the function window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() = function (){} and it works. Thanks!

Comment: i couln't able to get video url by player object while accessing same video id on second time

Comment: A bit more clarification if someone is still wondering -  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function must be defined globally. Simply replace the line

"function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {...." with 

"window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {...."

Comment: Perfect. Exactly my issue and quick solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Fortunately for me, after a lot of experimenting with console, I had something concrete. I kind of had the same issue until a day ago and figured out how to do when I was within a singleton scope.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var XT = XT || {};

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
    setTimeout(XT.yt.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady,500);
}

XT.yt = {

/* load the YouTube API first */
loadApi: function () {

        var j = document.createElement("script"),
            f = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        j.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        j.async = true;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        console.log('API Loaded');
    },

/*default youtube api listener*/
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady: function () {
    console.log('API Ready?');
    window.YT = window.YT || {};
    if (typeof window.YT.Player === 'function') {
        player = new window.YT.Player('player', {
            width: '640',
            height: '390',
            videoId: 'nE6mDCdYuwY',
            events: {
                onStateChange: XT.yt.onPlayerStateChange,
                onError: XT.yt.onPlayerError,
                onReady: setTimeout(XT.yt.onPlayerReady, 4000)
            }
        });
    }
},


onPlayerReady: function() {
    player.playVideo(); /* start the video */
    player.setVolume(1); /* set volume to 1 (accepts 0-100) */
},

onPlayerStateChange: function (e) {
    console.log(e.data, YT.PlayerState.PLAYING, e.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING);
    var video_data = e.target.getVideoData();

    //do something on video ends
    if(e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED)
    this.onPlayerStop();
},

onPlayerStop: function(){
    //console.log('video ended');
},

onPlayerError: function (e) {
    console.log( "youtube: " + e.target.src + " - " + e.data);
},

init: function () {
    this.loadApi();
}

}

XT.yt.init();
```

Comment: Also, for some weird reason I get an error on the consoles.

On Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Comment: Playing around and inserting setTimeout(function (){}, 1) to a few places did the trick for me

Comment: Works for me using `setTimeout`

Comment: Been trying different solutions. This seems to be working for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

Just to be clear, the accepted answer above seems to work for me in this way:

Load API (from yt documentation)

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

specify YouTube's built-in ready function "onYouTubeIframeAPIReady" on window

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = this.onYTready;
```

So `this.onYTready` is my function name and located elsewhere.
I can confirm my `onYTready` function can console logs/debugger breakpoints in Chrome.

(edit) you may want to bind this to your function, example:

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = this.onYTready.bind(this);
```

or 'this' will be for window instead of a specific view you may be using..

Comment: This method of specifically assigning the `onYouTubeIframeReady` event to `window` was the solution I was looking for when integrating the YouTube API with webpack.

Answer (score 1):

```
function playIframeVideo(iframe) {
    iframe.videoPlay = true; //init state
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
}

function pauseIframeVideo(iframe) {
    iframe.videoPlay = false; //init state
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
}

$('.vc_video-bg-container').on('click', function () {

    var iframe = $('iframe').get(0); //iframe tag

    if (iframe.videoPlay != true) {
        playIframeVideo(iframe);
    } else {
        pauseIframeVideo(iframe);
    }
});
```

Comment: Consider explaining your answer before helping with the code

Comment: This solution is helped me to fire play video on WPBakery page builder in background video for row.