# BackboneJS How to load Youtube Iframe in view

Tags: backbone.js, youtube, youtube-api

I have a Backbone App where I have a View in which I want to display a youtube player:

so in my View, in `afterRender` - I did this:

```
afterRender: function() {
              var tag = document.createElement('script');

              tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
              var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
              firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


              var player;
              function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('vid', {
                  height: '390',
                  width: '640',
                  videoId: '',
                  events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                  }
                });
              }

              function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
              }

              var done = false;
              function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                  setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                  done = true;
                }
              }
              function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
              }
}
```

But its not rendering anything but I also dont get errors and in my console I can see that Youtube API is loaded... So what am I doing wrong here?

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 // ...
}
```

into

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
 // ...
}
```

It now works! Found the clue here [Youtube iframe api not triggering onYouTubeIframeAPIReady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256382/youtube-iframe-api-not-triggering-onyoutubeiframeapiready)

Answer (score 1):

See this related question: [Youtube iframe api not triggering onYouTubeIframeAPIReady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256382/youtube-iframe-api-not-triggering-onyoutubeiframeapiready)

I think the problem is that your `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function needs to be declared globally, not nested inside another function.  (In your code, it's only defined within the scope of the `afterRender` method.)