# Importing YT and YTConfig from YouTube Iframe API meteor package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iframe, youtube

We're using the `adrianliaw:youtube-iframe-api` package to display youtube iframes in our project.

This was working fine before but we decided to move certain parts of our project into their own packages. After doing that, I can't seem to get the `YT` and `YTConfig` object imported into our packge.

This is what I have:

`package.js`:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('METEOR@0.9.1.1');

  // API Use - Both client and server
  api.use([
    'ecmascript',
    'templating',
    'fourseven:scss'
  ], ['client', 'server']);

  // API Use - Client only
  api.use([
    'adrianliaw:youtube-iframe-api'
  ], ['client']);
});
```

`youtube-display.js`:

```
import { YT, YTConfig } from 'meteor/adrianliaw:youtube-iframe-api';

/**
 * Video display controller
 * Assuming youtube-only for now
 */

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player,
    videoId,
    videoElement,
    isPreview = false,
    isMuted = false;

onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player(videoElement, {
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth,
        videoId: videoId,
        playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            rel: 0
        },
        events: {
            onReady: function (event) {
                if ( ! isPreview ) {
                    // Play video when player ready.
                    event.target.playVideo();

                    if ( isMuted ) {
                        event.target.mute();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

Template.HBModule_youtube_Display.onCreated(function() {
    videoId = Template.instance().data.media.youtubeId;

    if ( Template.instance().data.preview ) {
        isPreview = true;
    }

    if ( Template.instance().data.muted ) {
        isMuted = true;
    }
});

Template.HBModule_youtube_Display.onRendered(function() {
    videoElement = Template.instance().$('.module__video')[0];

    // Start
    YT.load();
});

Template.HBModule_youtube_Display.onDestroyed(function() {
    player.destroy()
});
```

and I'm getting this error:
`_adrianliawYoutubeIframeApi.YT.load is not a function`.

and like I said, minus the import at the top of the display file, this all worked perfect before.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was getting rid of the import at the top of `youtube-display.js` and changing the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function to `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` as per this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701359/5463842

EDIT: Oh! and also, adding `@1.3.122` to the package as mine was using an old version.