# onYouTubeIframeAPIReady on Angular2 can't find name 'YT' even when defined on global object

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

In an effort to capture the time at which a user pauses a youtube video ([that question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508040/record-how-far-into-a-video-a-user-hits-the-pause-button)), I have found myself using the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady callback method in Angular2.

I am having similar difficulties as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868225/onyoutubeiframeapiready-not-firing-on-angular2-web-app#) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811033/onyoutubeiframeapiready-on-angular2-cant-find-name-yt).

I followed the advice and ended up using `(window as any).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {}`.

In my onYouTubeIframeAPIReady method, though, I have the following code:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('video', {
    events: {
     'onReady': onPlayerReady,
     'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

I get the following error from my typescript linter:

> Argument of type '{events: {'onReady':(event:any) => void; 'onStateChange': (event:any)=>void;};}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PlayerOptions

My minimal example repo can be found here:

```
git clone https://github.com/Atticus29/dataJitsu.git
cd dataJitsu
git checkout stackoverflow
npm install
ng serve
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `window['YT']` instead of `YT` seems to solve this :

```
ngOnInit() {
  var player;

  window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = function() {
    player = new window['YT'].Player('video', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event){
    if (event.data == window['YT'].PlayerState.PAUSED) {
      console.log(player.getCurrentTime());
    }
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener("click", function() {
      player.pauseVideo();
    });
    document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function() {
      player.playVideo();
    });
  }

  if (!window['YT']){
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, @Bertrand Martel! Any idea why this works? What does window['YT'] actually do?