# Youtube player iframe API in web extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making a youtube `web extension`. How can I get a reference to `YT.Player` from the `content script` on a youtube video page (www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoId)?

In my main `content script` I have this (from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), but the function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` never fires:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");

  ////normally I would create the player like below, but I need the existing one
  //player = new YT.Player('player', {
  //    modestbranding: 1,
  //    cc_load_policy: 1,
  //    wmode: "opaque",
  //    height: '390',
  //    width: '640',
  //    videoId: videoId,
  //    enablejsapi: 1,
  //    events: {
  //        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
  //        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
  //        'onApiChange': onApiChange
  //    }
  //});
}
```

Interestingly, I can get the `player` from the browser console:

```
var player = $("#movie_player");
```

But this call doesn't work from the content script (I get a different kind of object).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256382/youtube-iframe-api-not-triggering-onyoutubeiframeapiready

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, I've seen that and tried to put the function in the background script (I'm still learning and experimenting) but to no avail..

Comment: I suspect the core problem here is that you're running in a sandbox - so your script isn't visible to the script running on the page, and vice-versa. Try injecting your logic directly into the page.